# Cauchy convergence test of a sequence

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove that the sequence

$
x_n = \frac{1}{n+1}
$

Converges using the Cauchy convergence test. Now I know the following

$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \enspace \exists N \enspace \forall n \geq N \enspace \forall m \geq N \\
|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon
$

What strategy do I use to express $N$ in terms of $\epsilon$?

Comment: It should be called a "sequence" rather than a series, since the term series usually refers to summing the terms, and your example is just about seeing if the terms converge to something using the Cauchy convergence test.

Comment: What do you know about the monotonicity of the function $t\mapsto \frac{1}{t}$ on $(0,+\infty)$?

Comment: It converges on 0.

Comment: Could we also just solve for N by arriving at the inequality n > something and setting N = something? This gives a different expression for N, but then when you work backwards you arrive at the same inequality as above, so I'm thinking this approach might also work. Does it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** For every $\varepsilon>0$ we can always find some $N\in\mathbb{N}^*$ such that 
$$\frac{1}{N+1}<\varepsilon.$$
Hence, for all $m,n>N$ we have (without loss of generality, assume that $m>n$ and hence $m=n+q$ for some $q\in\mathbb{N}^*$)
\begin{align*}
\bigg|\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{m+1}\bigg|&=\bigg|\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+q+1}\bigg|\\
&=\frac{q}{(n+1)(n+q+1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{(n+1)\cdot\Big(\frac{n+1}{q}+1\Big)}
\end{align*}
Notice that $\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{N+1}<\varepsilon$ and $\frac{n+1}{q}+1>1$, and hence we get that for all $n,m>N$
$$\bigg|\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{m+1}\bigg|<\varepsilon\cdot 1=\varepsilon.$$